# Does a subsequent crossing restriction supersede earlier crossing restrictions?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, sid-star

Does a subsequent crossing restriction supersede earlier crossing restrictions?

Here's an example.

While flying the MIP4 arrival into KLGA, you receive the expected instruction to cross MARRC at FL180. Before reaching MARRC, you receive the instruction to cross BILEY at 13,000. These fixes being expected is not material to the example. The question is, when given the subsequent instruction to cross BILEY at 13,000, does this supersede the instruction to cross MARRC at FL180.

If possible, please cite answers in 14 CFR, AIM, or another FAA source.

[image: MIP4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AIM 4-4-10 (g) gives us guidance on this situation.

> The guiding principle is that the last ATC
>   clearance has precedence over the previous ATC
>   clearance. When the route or altitude in a previously
>   issued clearance is amended, the controller will
>   restate applicable altitude restrictions. If altitude to
>   maintain is changed or restated, whether prior to
>   departure or while airborne, and previously issued
>   altitude restrictions are omitted, those altitude
>   restrictions are canceled, including departure procedures
>   and STAR altitude restrictions.

For the example in the question, unless the controller restated the requirement to cross MARCC at FL180, that clearance is cancelled by the issuance of the clearance to cross BILEY at 13,000.